# Quest about react redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, state

When I want to implement a shopping cart, and I add an item in the state on the homepage.js. I get correct state in homepage.js. However, I get state in the cart.js is incorrect. Can help me check what mistake I got? Thank you!

Here my reducer.js

```
const shoppingCartReducer = (state=[], action) => {
    
    const {type, payload} = action;
    
    switch(type){
        case ADD_ITEM_TO_CART:
            console.log("state add to cart",state);
            return [...state, payload];
        
        case REMOVE_TIEM_FROM_CART:
            return state.filter(item => item !== payload);
        
        case CLEAR_THE_CART:
            return state = [];
        
        default:
            console.log("state", state);
            return state;
    }
    
    
}

export default shoppingCartReducer;
```

Here my store.js

```
const reducers = combineReducers({
    shoppingCartReducer: shoppingCartReducer
})

const store = createStore(
    reducers,
    composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware))
)

export default store;
```

Here is my homepage.js, I add item in the state through 'props.addToCart(product1)' and I get correct state in this page.

```
....
<CardDeck className='m-1'>
                <Card border='warning' className='ml-3 mt-2 p-2'>
                    <Card.Link href="/productPage">
                            <Card.Img variant="top" src='../images/camera.jpg' />
                        </Card.Link>
                       <Card.Body>
                        <Card.Title>Camera</Card.Title>
                            <Card.Text>Brand: CANNON</Card.Text>
                            <Card.Text>Price: $600</Card.Text>
                            <Card.Text>Description: CANNON EOS 80D DSLR CAMERA
                            </Card.Text>
                           <Button variant="warning"
                                   onClick={() => props.addToCart(product1)}

                           >Add to cart
                           </Button>
                        </Card.Body>
                </Card>
                <Card border='warning' className='ml-3 mt-2 p-2'>
                    <Card.Link href="/productPage">
                        <Card.Img variant="top" src='../images/mouse.jpg' />
                    </Card.Link>
                    <Card.Body>
                        <Card.Title>Mouse</Card.Title>
                        <Card.Text>Brand: LOGITECH</Card.Text>
                        <Card.Text>Price: $100</Card.Text>
                        <Card.Text>Description:  LOGITECH G-SERIES GAMING MOUSE
                        </Card.Text>
                        <Button variant="warning"
                                onClick={() => props.addToCart(product2)}
....

const mapDispatchtoProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        addToCart: (item) => {
            dispatch(addItemToCart({item}));
        }
    }
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchtoProps)(HomePage);
```

Here is my cart.js

```
const Cart = (props) => {
    ....
    //productsInCart is empty array
    const productsInCart = props.itemsInCart;
    console.log("productsInCart,",productsInCart);
    ....
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    console.log("state in cart,", state);
    return {itemsInCart: state.shoppingCartReducer};
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Cart);
```

Here is my app.js

```
function App() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <Header/>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path='/' exact component={HomePage}/>
                    <Route path='/cart' component={Cart}/>
                </Switch>
                <Footer />
        </Router>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Here is my index.js:

```
ReactDOM.render(
      <Provider store={store}><App /></Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing props to the `<Cart />` component. This is why when you are looking for something there, it does not exist.

You either pass it from above through props:

```
function CartWithProps({children}) {
  return (
    <Cart itemsInCart={itemsInCart}>
      {children}
    </Cart>
  );
}

<Route path='/cart' component={CartWithProps}/>
```

or consume state from store provider inside the component

```
// could be something like this
const Cart = (props) => {
    ....
    const productsInCart = useSelector(getItemsInCart);
    console.log("productsInCart", productsInCart);
    ....
    )
}
```

or another guess will be that you have changed order of parameters sent into `connect` function:

```js
//null first
export default connect(null, mapDispatchtoProps)(HomePage);
//null second
export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Cart);
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. In the third guess, do you mean I fix to export default connect(null, mapDispatchtoProps)(HomePage); and export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Cart);   In the second guess, I do not understand where the getItemsInCart comes from?

Comment: @KyFend, I also do not know but based on your description, it seems to have null first like in homepage.js make it work. So, I suggest you make null first and into cart.js

Comment: Thank you! I tried it, but it still not work. I tried all your methods. I don't know why.

Comment: When you are going from homepage.js to the cart.js - your page is reloading (this means everything on your page disappears and load from 0) or you are changing only the view (this means your page is just hiding one component and showing another)?